# How do I get the Spark 2.0.0 SparkContext and SparkSql functions working in the scalatest/junit test environment?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Since migrating to Spark 2.0.0, some SparkContext and SparkSql functions(e.g. textFile, parallelize, read.load)  no longer work
in the scala unit test environment although they do work outside of the test environment in my Main class.
When the code attempts to execute each of these functions in the test environment, a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError occurs. 
Note that the same problem exists when using Spark 2.0.0 whether I use SparkSession or the old SparkContext and SparkSql. 
Also, it is important noting that the same functions do work in the test environment when I use Spark 1.6. 
Any ideas for a solution to this problem?  Both the test code and the stack trace (associated with the execution of 
spark.sparkContext.textFile) with the error are below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, FunSuite}

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestSparkFunctions extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  val master = "local[2]"
  val appName = "test"
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName(appName)
    .master(master)
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", System.getProperty("user.dir"))
    .getOrCreate()
  val textFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile("people.txt")

  test("test spark functions") {

    //    val peopleDf = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat")
    //      .option("header", "true")
    //      .option("delimiter", "\\t")
    //      .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
    //      .option("inferSchema", "true")
    //       .load(getClass.getResource("/people.txt").getPath)

    //    val lines = Source.fromFile(getClass.getResource("/people.txt").getPath).getLines.toSeq
    //    val linesRdd: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(lines)
  }
  override def afterAll() = {
    if (spark != null) spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Stack Trace Error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:682)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:800)
at com.corelogic.TestSparkFunctions.<init>(TestSparkFunctions.scala:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:468)
at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)
at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:207)
at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Jackson version is too old 2.4.4
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:56)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:549)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:682)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:800)
at com.corelogic.TestSparkFunctions.<init>(TestSparkFunctions.scala:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:468)
at sbt.TestRunner.runTest$1(TestFramework.scala:76)
at sbt.TestRunner.run(TestFramework.scala:85)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFramework$.sbt$TestFramework$$withContextLoader(TestFramework.scala:185)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFramework$$anon$2$$anonfun$$init$$1.apply(TestFramework.scala:202)
at sbt.TestFunction.apply(TestFramework.scala:207)
at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
at sbt.Tests$$anonfun$9.apply(Tests.scala:216)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:44)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into same issue. Underlying issue here is:

> Jackson version is too old 2.4.4

Resolved this by using newer version "2.6.5" that Spark 2.x supports. `"com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5"`

ref:[spark pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml)